# strange docker error when stop and starting a container

Tags: docker, coreos

I have been stopping and starting this container with no problem.  Then suddenly I get this strange error.

see history of commands below

```
core@ip-10-32-251-200 /vol/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
241d05c8d14f        joshuacalloway/jenkins:latest   "/usr/bin/supervisor   5 weeks ago         Up 6 days           0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp   jenkins             
core@ip-10-32-251-200 /vol/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib $ docker stop 241
241
core@ip-10-32-251-200 /vol/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib $ docker start 241
241
core@ip-10-32-251-200 /vol/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib $ docker stop 241
241
core@ip-10-32-251-200 /vol/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib $ docker start 241
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 241: Unit docker-241d05c8d14f0b9f18d4f8647ac76a27097354aab5d92f1aaa6c9789a85e6e3d.scope already exists.
2014/09/05 00:27:39 Error: failed to start one or more containers
core@ip-10-32-251-200 /vol/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib $ docker start 241
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 241: Unit docker-241d05c8d14f0b9f18d4f8647ac76a27097354aab5d92f1aaa6c9789a85e6e3d.scope already exists.
2014/09/05 00:27:47 Error: failed to start one or more containers
```

Comment: What do you get when you `docker ps`, `docker ps -a` and `docker logs` the container?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a issue [detailed here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7015). In the meanwhile you can workaround like this:

`sudo systemctl stop docker-241d05c8d14f0b9f18d4f8647ac76a27097354aab5d92f1aaa6c9789a85e6e3d.scope`

then start yout container

Comment: ok it looks like that could be the solution.  I'll try it next time I get that error